# playframework - Can't read cookie from request

Tags: session, playframework, session-cookies

How can I get the cookie from a request in playframework?
I have the following test endpoint

```
def home = Action.async { implicit request =>
    println(request)
    println(request.session)
    println(request.flash)
    request.session.get("session") match {
      case Some(cookie) => Future(Ok(cookie))
      case None =>
        Future(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> "missing session cookie")))
    }
  }
```

When submitting the following request:

```
curl 'http://local.example.com:9000/home' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cookie: session=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI...' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
```

I unfortunately get the "missing session cookie" response. and the following printout on the console

```
GET /home
Session(Map())
Flash(Map())
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: I set the cookie using the following method:

```
def tokenLogin = Action(parse.json).async { implicit request =>
    val loginRequest = request.body.validate[LoginRequest]
    loginRequest.fold(
      errors =>
      {
        println(errors)
        Future(BadRequest(Json.obj("message" -> JsError.toJson(errors))))
      },
      request => {
        println("in success")
        firebaseAdminService
          .createSessionCookie(request.idToken)
          .map(sessionCookie =>
            Ok("success")
              .withNewSession
              .withCookies(Cookie(name = "session", value = sessionCookie))
          )
      }
    )
  }
```

Comment: beware with posting JWT data publicly, since these can contain sensitive information (e.g. your email address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the session cookie in Play is called "PLAY_SESSION" (configuration `play.http.session.cookieName`).

So, you would need to use `-H "Cookie: PLAY_SESSION=..."` with curl.

But note, this won't work with arbitrary data since Play uses JWT and signs the information contained in the session cookie using its crypto secret.

The only thing expected to work is using a session cookie received in a `Set-Cookie` header from your Play service in another request to the same service (having the same secret).

---

**update after your edit**:

When using `request.session`, you are accessing the session cookie, which is called `PLAY_SESSION` and the information stored inside it.

But, you are setting a cookie of your own. This is something else.

You can access "normal" cookies with

```
request.cookies.get("session")
```

Oh, and in case you really wanted to make use of the session cookie, you can set it like this:

```
Ok("success").withSession("session" -> sessionCookie)
```

Comment: I know the default name is PLAY_SESSION, but I set the cookie using `.withCookies(Cookie(name = "session", value = sessionCookie))`. So the cookie should be there. I added the method adding the session cookie too the question. If you have another idea please let me know.